# How to stop a Javascript function call within setTimeout after it has been fired?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div that listens for a "mouseenter" event, and fires a libraryFunction (that I cannot edit) after 5 seconds (implemented with setTimeout).

However, if the user clicks the div within those 5 seconds, the setTimeout should be cancelled, and the function should not run (implemented with clearTimeout). The click will also remove an element that the libraryFunction relies on.

Currently I have the code below:

```
var timeoutVar;
$("#mydiv").on("mouseenter", function(event) {
    timeoutVar =  setTimeout(function() {
        runLibraryFunction(object);
    }, 5000);
});

$("#mydiv").on("click", function(event) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutVar);
    removeObject(object);
});
```

This works for the most part, however, there is an edge case when the div is clicked just after 5 seconds, and while runLibraryFunction() in executing.
Because the "click" event removes the object that the runLibraryFunction needs, and this happens while runLibraryFunction is running, runLibraryFunction then throws an error.

Is there a way to stop the runLibraryFunction() call after it has been fired?

Comment: What is the need to remove the object after clicking?

Comment: This looks like an XY Problem, what about you just do the removal `removeObject()` at the end in your `runLibraryFunction` function when it's done with it?

Comment: I would suggest, inside timeout trigger click event instead of calling function directly. This will make code flow a bit cleaner. Also once click is fired, you can set a flag like `processing` and in its false state only, call functions.

Comment: Also, you can `.off()` `click` event before `runLibraryFunction` in `setTimeout` function. So that if it started to run library function, then there is no way back. There will be only two cases: clicked before 5 seconds passed - object has been removed; 5 seconds passed - library function will run and finish execution.

Comment: This smells like a design flaw with that removal that you need to detect or avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a property to the object when starting the library function thereby protecting it from being removed like:

```
var timeoutVar;
$("#mydiv").on("mouseenter", function(event) {
    timeoutVar =  setTimeout(function() {
        object.keepmealive=1;
        runLibraryFunction(object);
        if (object) delete object.keepmealive;
    }, 5000);
});

$("#mydiv").on("click", function(event) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutVar);
    if (!object.keepmealive) removeObject(object);
});
```

This approach assumes that your library function will somehow take care of deleting or doing whatever needs to be done to `object`, so once it has started running there is no necessity for the delete function any more. It will stay in place and will be ready to act on another possible future event.

Answer (score 2):

Tricky but will work

```
timeoutVar =  setTimeout(function() {
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            if(object)
            runLibraryFunction(object);
        },1000);
    }, 5000);
```

Keep rest same.

or use immediately invoked functions

```
timeoutVar =  setTimeout(function() {
                  (function(object){ 
                      runLibraryFunction(object);
                   })(object);
              }, 5000);
```

Now object will always be accessible

Comment: Using nested timeout will just add buffer of about 1-1.5 sec. If processing takes more than that, problem will persist. Also is there a difference between calling function directly and using IIFE?

Comment: Yes ofcourse IIFE will let the `object` wo be always in scope of `runLibraryFunction`

Comment: will adding a simple if condition not solve it? I guess adding a flag would be a better approach than using IIFE or nested timeouts

Answer (score 0):

I would unbind the event during processing, and rebind it afterwards using s recursive function like so:

```
var timeoutVar;
var init = function(){
  $("#mydiv").on("mouseenter", function(event) {
    timeoutVar =  setTimeout(function() {
        $("#mydiv").off()
        runLibraryFunction(object, function(){
          init()
        });
    }, 5000);
  });
};

$("#mydiv").on("click", function(event) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutVar);
    removeObject(object);
});

init();
```